# CMMotionManager with a serial queue

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, accelerometer

I have a serial queue to receive both Gyro and Accelerometer motion update at interval of 0.01 second.

From the logs I can see two blocks are executed on different threads, as `NSMutableArray` is not thread safe and I also modify the array in both blocks,  is it safe for me to manipulate the array this way?

I also read that tasks on a serial queue is executed one at a time, if only one of the two motions is monitored, is it safe to modify the array?

```
@implementation NSThread (GetSequenceNumber)

- (NSInteger)number
{
    return [[self valueForKeyPath:@"private.seqNum"] integerValue];
}

@end

@interface SensorCollector()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *array;

@end

@implementation SensorCollector
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.motionManager = [CMMotionManager new];
        self.queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
        self.queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;
        _array = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)starCollect {
    float updateInterval = 0.01;//50Hz

    //setup sensors callback in background NSOperationQueue
    if ([self.motionManager isAccelerometerAvailable]) {
        [self.motionManager setAccelerometerUpdateInterval:updateInterval];
        [self.motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:self.queue withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData, NSError *error) {
            //modify self.array here
            NSLog(@"Acce %ld", [NSThread currentThread].number);
        }];
    }

    if ([self.motionManager isGyroAvailable]) {
        [self.motionManager setGyroUpdateInterval:updateInterval];
        [self.motionManager startGyroUpdatesToQueue:self.queue withHandler:^(CMGyroData *gyroData, NSError *error) {
            //also modify self.array here
            NSLog(@"Gyro %ld", [NSThread currentThread].number);
        }];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be safe. The handler blocks will be executed sequentially on your `NSOperationQueue`, due to the fact that you've set `maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1`.

If you want to be doubly sure, you could lock the array when modifying it, by performing the operations inside a `@synchronized` block:

```
@synchronized(self.array) {
    // Modify self.array here...
}
```

That said, I don't think this is necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, `@synchronized` is a little bit expensive though.